# How can I transfer a pointer variable from one cython module to another using a Python script

Tags: python, cython

Assume we have a cython class `A` with a pointer to `float` like in

```
# A.pyx
cdef class A:
    cdef float * ptr
```

We also have a cython class `B` in another module which needs access to the data under `ptr`:

```
# B.pyx

cdef class B:
    cdef float * f_ptr

    cpdef submit(self, ptr_var):
        self.f_ptr= get_from( ptr_var ) # ???
```

The corresponding Python code using `A` and `B` might be something like

```
from A import A
from B import B

a = A()
b = B()
ptr = a.get_ptr()
b.submit(ptr)
```

How can we define `get_ptr()` and what would we use for `get_from` in `B`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to wrap the pointer variable into a Python object. Module libc.stdint offers a type named `uintptr_t` which is an integer large enough for storing any kind of pointer. With this the solution might look as follows.

```
from libc.stdint cimport uintptr_t
cdef class A:
    cdef float * ptr

    def get_ptr(self):
        return <uintptr_t>self.ptr
```

The expression in angle brackets `<uintptr_t>` corresponds to a cast to `uintptr_t`. In class B we then have to cast the variable back to a pointer to float.

```
from libc.stdint cimport uintptr_t
cdef class B:
    cdef float * f_ptr

    cpdef submit(self, uintptr_t ptr_var):
        self.f_ptr= <float *>ptr_var
```

This works for any kind of pointers not only for pointers to float. One has to make sure that both modules (`A` and `B`) deal with the same kind of pointer since that information is lost once the pointer is wrapped in a `uintptr_t`.